# fetch email address that does not contain certain words from webpage

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Please tell me how can I extract emails (1st match) that does not contain words 'ajax' and 'gif' within email address. Here's the basic regex that I have:

```
match = re.findall('([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.\w+)', q.read(), re.I)[0]
```

Thanks,

Comment: You mean within the user part, or the entire email address? For example is `foo@gif.com` valid?

Comment: Do you need the regex to return just the first result or all? re.findall will return all matching results. If you want just the first result, use re.match

Comment: 1) entire email address

Comment: 2) i know about re.match thanks - this is just a design of script

Comment: @user1192422 post some examples.

Comment: need fetching word@domain.com and avoid, say, ajax@2x.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
\b(?!\S*(?:ajax|gif)\S*)([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.\w+)\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/13)